# EXC_BAD_ACCESS strange Hex to String conversion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm stuck.
I give you the exact code which I use, not a sample:

So, I make two strings like this:

```
DestChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", [DestField integerValue]];
SourceChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", [SourceField integerValue]];
```

So the user write the Source/Dest in Decimal value but they are stocked as hex in a string, and then I have a button which reformat the source & dest like this:

```
NSString * CommandReadyToSend  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X:0/%@,%@\r", DestChoice, SourceChoice];
```

My code is working, BUT, strangly some values makes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the CommandReadyToSend part...
Example: If I write 1 in my text field => I receive 1 (hex value) as result in DestChoice
If I write 10 in my text field => I receive A in DestChoice

BUT If I write 31 in the text field, I'm supposed to get 1F, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
Same thing with 29 (dec value)

It seems that certains hex value can't be reformatted to string, I don't understand...

Comment: Cannot check it now but try replacing %lX with %X

Comment: Where and how are `DestChoice` and `SourceChoice` declared?

Comment: They are declared as strings: NSString * DestChoice = @""; NSString * SourceChoice = @"";

Comment: I replaced %lX by %X -> no changes, still EXC_BAD_ACCESS with some values like 31 (dec) which is supposed to result "1F"...

Comment: They are declared in the @synthetize, but why for dec values like 10 it's working? returning my command like X:0/1,A... but for "31" I get this strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working for me, the cause must be elsewhere.

```
    NSString *destChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", 1];
    NSString *sourceChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX", 31];
    NSString *commandReadyToSend  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X:0/%@,%@\r", destChoice, sourceChoice];
    NSLog(@"%@", commandReadyToSend);
```

`2012-05-10 13:56:29.092 test[9383:707] X:0/1,1F`

-

btw; If `DestField` is a `UITextField` then you should be using `[DestField.text integerValue];` - this is probability your problem.

Comment: It is NSTextField, so [DestField integerValue] is ok

Comment: Problem solved! [DestChoice retain]; did the trick!